# Sequential file reads incorrect file data in IBM datastage 8.1

Tags: sequential, datastage

The scenario which i am facing is as follows :

A sequential file is generated with for example 100 rows in the name of A.txt .. the same sequential file is required as input in another job but this time when it reads its taking the  rows as 140 but physically oly 100 rows are there. I have analysed so much for this ind Datastage  like verifyin the property for columns , delimiters , project comparison.. but still i am not able to .. .
if any one can help me out in this problem wud b highly appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the file name - if both are same file written to and read, was the record count checked in Unix/Linux - at times the monitor in the director might not show the current count

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the name of the file in output stage and in input stage.